# A parameters.yml per bundle, symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I was wondering if it's possible to defined a parameters.yml file for every bundle or only for the bundles that need it and load those.

I have searched a lot but i can't find such solution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Just asking, because I'm interpreting your question in two different ways. Add a parameters.yml file to your own bundle? Or use a global parameters.yml file for a list of your own bundles?

Comment: i should be able to use a new connection that i specified in a bundle (not global)

Comment: In that case, Thomas wrote out the answer already ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should clarify a bit; you want every single bundles to automatically include a `parameters.yml` file? I am afraid you would need to modify Symfony's DI core. There is an easy alternative though.

If you create your own bundle with some `DependencyInjection` then you can add `$loader->load('parameters.yml');` in the bundle's extension class.

The extension class should be located in `YourBundle/DependencyInjection/YourBundleExtension.php`.

The class should look like the following

```
class YourBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('parameters.yml'); // Adding the parameters file
    }
}
```

So in this case the `parameters.yml` file would be in `YourBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml`.

Comment: I think the order of imports matters. If `services.yml` requires some parameters that are defined in `parameters.yml`, you can run into some trouble, because those aren't known yet. Or am I seeing this the wrong way?

Comment: I just tried and it worked; it is possible to use a parameter from a file loaded later. My guess is that Symfony compiles the config file afterwards when every parameters have been merged and de-duplicated. However it doesn't seem to work across bundles.

Comment: And how can i add this to the doctrine configuration as well (so i get a new connection)

Comment: I don't think it's possible and you would probably need to use a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to inject a new connection.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to include a parameters file from a bundle into your configuration, just follow the normal format for importing extra configuration files from bundles (the default app shows how to do this with routing). Update your config to include your parameters file like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: @YourBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - ...
```

Your parameters file should follow the same format as the default one:

```
parameters:
    my.parameter: "my value"
```

Comment: that would only work for the first import, because the second import (from the bundle) would override the parameters content from the first import. see why: https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection/blob/master/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php#L120-123

Comment: That would only overwrite individual parameters with the same name, not the whole lot. In my limited experience of one project, I am successfully using a main parameters.yml and a bundle parameters.yml with both sets available in the app (though my second bundle doesn't have it's own parameters, I wouldn't expect to have any problems unless the parameters were called the same thing).

Comment: Mh strange, I tried it with the latest 2.4.3 and it was not successful . Maybe it was just me doing something wrong.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get an error "There is no extension able to load the configuration for "parameters"".