# Twig global variable per bundle, Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764186/3390057 for A "parameters.yml per bundle, symfony2".
Currently global variables are available for each of the bundles. I need to add global variables in twig for each bundle. It is possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

*global* *per bundle* seems rather strange to me. I assume you want to set a global variable from within a bundle, am I correct? In that case, use a TwigExtension, as explained in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#using-a-twig-extension

Comment: But this is not per bundle, it is the global configuration way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per [these docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html), you can simply add this to your injected `whatever.yml` file that you've added to your bundle:

```
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        foo: bar
```

Then you refer back to it in your Twig templates using `{{ foo }}`

To inject your `whatever.yml` file to your Bundle configuration (and back into Symfony), you should [follow these instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#using-the-load-method). This is where you add the following line to your `load()` function of the `Extension` file located in `DependencyInjection` (generally it's made when you use `php app/console generate:bundle`):

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

// ...
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );
    $loader->load('services.yml');
    $loader->load('whatever.yml'); // Your new line
}
```

Comment: but my parameters.yml is not in app/config/ because it is now in Resource/config/ of each bundle, so the config.yml not find the variable. This is why we need to define variables for each twig bundle. A file that defines global variables for each twig bundle

Comment: @fgonzalez That's why I said "add this **to your injected `whatever.yml` file**"... I saw your reference to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17764186/1188035) and incorrectly deduced that you would've figured out how to inject that file from reading the previous answer, but since you didn't, I've edited for further instructions.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work per-bundle, because the "twig" namespace does not appear to be available in any configurations loaded by dependency injection.