# Custom parameters file error

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Due to Sensio Insight constraints I'm attempting to move parameters from `app/config/parameters.yml` to the application bundle but continue to get

> You have requested a non-existent parameter
>   "truckee_volunteer.sandbox"

This is because `app/config/config.yml` contains (along with other references from the bundle's `parameters.yml`)

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: @TruckeeVolunteerBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml }
    ...
    twig:
        ...
        globals:
            sandbox: "%truckee_volunteer.sandbox%"
```

This attempt is based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763622/a-parameters-yml-per-bundle-symfony2)

#### Extension class

```
class TruckeeVolunteerExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /* for Sensio Insight
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        */

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('parameters.yml');
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'truckee_volunteer';
    }
```

#### Configuration class

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('truckee_volunteer');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('admin_user')
                    ->defaultValue('admin')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
                ->scalarNode('admin_password')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
                ->arrayNode('admin_email')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('address')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
                ->scalarNode('admin_first_name')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
                ->scalarNode('admin_last_name')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
                ->booleanNode('sandbox')
                    ->defaultFalse()
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

#### Bundle's parameters.yml

```
truckee_volunteer:
    admin_user: admin
    admin_password: 123Abcd
    admin_email: 
        address: admin@example.com
    admin_first_name: Benny
    admin_last_name: Borko
    sandbox: false
```

Comment: having a parameters.yml in a bundle is not good practice.  Once you've read the values from the config.yml you're supposed to add the parameters to the container manually in the dependency injection.

Comment: @DerickF Perhaps I'm unclear on dependency injection.  The extension & configuration classes above are in the bundle's DependencyInjection directory & namespace.  The fundamental problem is how best to define parameters that can be used in `app/config/config.yml` and be injected into services. This is what I thought I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the bundle's `parameters.yml` file is not read until after `app/config/config.yml` is processed.  This was determined by placing an `exit("Bailing out of the Extension class!!");` command inside the bundle's Extension class.  That command was not run unless the `app/config/config.yml` did not contain any parameters of the form `"%truckee_volunteer.*%"`.

If I'm not making this up, then it is not possible to define replaceable parameters in a bundle.  Can anyone confirm this?

#### Further testing:

I cannot fully explain or understand the behavior.  If the bundle's `parameters.yml` file is modified to

```
parameters:
    truckee_volunteer.admin_user: admin
    truckee_volunteer.admin_password: 123Abcd
    truckee_volunteer.admin_email.address: admin@bogus.info
    truckee_volunteer.admin_first_name: Benny
    truckee_volunteer.admin_last_name: Borko
    truckee_volunteer.sandbox: false
```

then these parameters are replaceable in `app/config/config.yml`.  There may be other requirements, but through the many trials I have not sorted them out.

I've backed off of this approach anyway now that I understand the Sensio Insight constraint that got me to look at doing this.  It turns out that one may extend the default `parameters.yml.dist` but if an e-mail address is included it must specify an RFC compliant default address. Putting all the custom parameters in `parameters.yml.dist` is substantially easier and more effective.